# how to populate html table with WL.JSONStore data

Tags: javascript, json, ibm-mobilefirst

I am working in worklight hybrid app,i have created JSON store and added data in that one,i need to populate the JSON store data in html table?

Comment: Add Json Data and html structure what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Why not take a look at the [JSONStore sample project](http://public.dhe.ibm.com/software/mobile-solutions/worklight/docs/v610/JSONStoreAPIBasicsProject.zip) provided as part of [the documentation for JSONStore in Worklight](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#advanced-client-side-development), and see how data is retrieved from it?